# MS SQL not exist where more columns are

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table 1 from which I need take and ad to table2 only rows which is not in table 2

```
Table 1
ID  Name    N   T
A   Bob    33   Y
B   Eva    44   N
C   John   47   Y
B   Alex   44  N
D   Bob    47  Y

Table 2 
ID  Name   N   T
A   Bob    34  Y
B   Alex   44  N
D   Bob    47  Y
```

I try set up this type of version script but i get duplicity of whole table 1 + new rows

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2
  (ID , Name ,  N ,  T)
SELECT table1.ID,  table1.Name,   table1.N,   table1.T
FROM TABLE_1 table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM TABLE_2 table2
                 WHERE (table2.ID = table1.ID) and (table2.Name = table1.Name) and (table2.N = table1.N )AND (table2.T =  table1.T))
```

Expect Result

```
A   Bob    34   Y
B   Alex   44   N
D   Bob    47   Y
A   Bob    33   Y
B   Eva    44   N
C   John   47   Y
```

Comment: I have tested your script and it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/261ff/5/1 Thanks for wasting my time

Comment: Read about EXCEPT. SQLs without it (or MINUS) can use a LEFT JOIN idiom instead.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a select query identifying all records in `table1` which do not completely match some record in `table2`.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (ID, Name, N, T)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.N, t1.T
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.ID   = t2.ID   AND
       t1.Name = t2.Name AND
       t1.N    = t2.N    AND
       t1.T    = t2.T
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Note that the logic here is that if even one column of a given record in `table1` be not in agreement with a certain record in `table2`, then the join would fail, and all `table2` columns would then come up `NULL` in the result set.  The `WHERE` clause restricts to only such non matching records in `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could join both tables with a left join. 
 
All records from Table_1 who don't have a match with Table_2 have to be inserted. To check which record doesn't have a match you can simply use `T2.ID IS NULL`

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (ID , Name ,  N ,  T)
      SELECT T1.ID
            ,T1.Name
            ,T1.N
            ,T1.T
        FROM TABLE_1 T1 
   LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 T2
          ON T1.ID    = T2.ID
         AND T1.Name  = T2.Name
         AND T1.N     = T2.N
         AND T1.T     = T2.T
       WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Table1 table (ID varchar(100),  Name varchar(100),   N int,   T varchar(100));
insert into @Table1 values
('A',   'Bob',    33,   'Y'),
('B',   'Eva',    44,   'N'),
('C',   'John',   47,   'Y'),
('B',   'Alex',   44,  'N'),
('D',   'Bob',    47,  'Y')

declare @Table2 table (ID varchar(100),  Name varchar(100),   N int,   T varchar(100));
insert into @Table2 values
('A',   'Bob',    34,   'Y'),
('B',   'Alex',   44,  'N'),
('D',   'Bob',    47,  'Y')

insert into @Table2
select *
from @Table1 t1
where not exists (select * 
                  from @Table2 t2
                  where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.N= t1.N and t2.Name = t1.Name and t1.T = t2.T);
```